# Asp.net MVC and JSON date format exception - The value '/Date(251071200000)/' is not valid for Date Of Birth

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, datetime

I get the following exception when posting my JSON object back to Asp.net MVC:

```
"The value '/Date(251071200000)/' is not valid for Date Of Birth."
```

Looking in Firebug there's definitely a value being posted back so I assume there's some problem in model binding. If I track the DateOfBirth property's set section the 'value' is null.

---

### The Setup Is

C# POCO object with a DateOfBirth property as follows:

```
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth
    {
        get
        {
            return ClientDto.Contact.DateOfBirth;
        }
        set
        {
            ClientDto.Contact.DateOfBirth = value;
        }
    }
```

The controller action sends the JSON data to the calling AJAX function as follows (Note: we've tried two options here): 
Option 1:

```
/*...extract and initialize a profile object...*/
return Json(profile, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Option 2:

```
/*...extract and initialize a profile object...*/
return Json(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(profile), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

We post the JSON data back from the client side as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.editForm.prop("action"),

    data: kendo.stringify(copy),  //can be replaced with JSON.stringify

    type: "POST",

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    success: function (args)
    {
        //done
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not very clear on the question but assuming you do get a value back to MVC and, if the error is related to the JSON date format i.e. **'/Date(251071200000)/'**, then i had the same problem.

Basically what you are passing is JSON format of Date. You need to convert date (either on client side or server) to a proper date format.

I used the function below to convert **"/Date(210355200000)/"** to ***"1/9/1976"***

```
function fromJsonToJavaScriptDate(value) {
var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
var results = pattern.exec(value);
var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
return dt.getDate() + "/" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getFullYear();}
```

you can use this function on client like ;

```
$dob = fromJsonToJavaScriptDate([your date value])
```

you can find the way to convert this json date format on server as explained in the link below.

http://www.developer.com/net/dealing-with-json-dates-in-asp.net-mvc.html

I hope this helps.